# Spacing after itemize (without parskip package)

Tags: spacing, lists, line-spacing, enumitem

This piece of code seemed to be working fine for a long time, until I try to *remove* the `parskip` package. Without this package, it seems that I need to include two hacks:

1. Add a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` *before* and *after* the `itemize` environment.
2. Need a `\strut` to be added.

So without `parskip`, and *with* these two hacks I obtain the desired results:

[image]

But without the hacks, which is obtained by ensuring the following are un-commented:

```
\renewcommand{\HackVSpace}{}%
\renewcommand{\HackStrut}{}%
```

this yields:

[image]

Surely there is a less hackish solution to this.  And, what is special about `parskip` that I was getting the desired behavior.

### Notes:

- In actual usage I am only really using this for a *single* item and `itemize` provides the desired formatting, so I could do without `itemize`. But am still interested to know how to control `itemize`.

### Code:

```
%\def\UseParskipPackage{}% Need to work with this commented.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\ifdefined\UseParskipPackage
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \newcommand{\HackVSpace}{}%
    \newcommand{\HackStrut}{}%
\else
    \newcommand{\HackVSpace}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%
    \newcommand{\HackStrut}{\strut}%
\fi


%% Remove the hack - comment these out and things work fine
%% with or without the parskip package
    \renewcommand{\HackVSpace}{}%
    \renewcommand{\HackStrut}{}%


\begin{document}

\noindent
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \HackVSpace%
            \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{X:}}]%
                \item \HackStrut\texttt{some text fff yyy}%
            \end{itemize}%
            \HackVSpace%
            }}%
%
\newline
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \HackVSpace%
            \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{Y:}}]%
                \item \HackStrut\texttt{some more text fff yyy}%
            \end{itemize}%
            \HackVSpace%
            }%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would adding the `nosep` option to `itemize` help?

Comment: @egreg: Well, it seems to do a _lot_ more than help -- it seems to fix the problem completely!!! :-) Thanks. Testing in actual use case now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parskip` package changes the definition of `\@listi`, `\@listii` and `\@listiii` to use different values for the parameters `\topsep`, `\itemsep` and `\parsep`; it sets the first two to zero and the third to `\parskip`.

This explains why you don't get additional space in the box when `parskip` is loaded. When it isn't, the normal spacings are applied.

Solution, independent on `parskip`: add `nosep` to the options passed to `itemize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{
    \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{X:}},nosep]
    \item \texttt{some text fff yyy}
    \end{itemize}
  }%
}
\newline
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{
    \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{Y:}},nosep]
    \item \texttt{some more text fff yyy}
    \end{itemize}
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

space is discarded at the top of pages, but not at the top of boxes. LaTeX emulates this behaviour, which is the main difference between `minipage` and `\parbox`

[image]

```
%\def\UseParskipPackage{}% Need to work with this commented.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\ifdefined\UseParskipPackage
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \newcommand{\HackVSpace}{}%
    \newcommand{\HackStrut}{}%
\else
    \newcommand{\HackVSpace}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%
    \newcommand{\HackStrut}{\strut}%
\fi


%% Remove the hack - comment these out and things work fine
%% with or without the parskip package
    \renewcommand{\HackVSpace}{}%
    \renewcommand{\HackStrut}{}%


\begin{document}

\noindent
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \HackVSpace%
            \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{X:}}]%
                \item \HackStrut\texttt{some text fff yyy}%
            \end{itemize}%
            \HackVSpace%
            }}%
%
\newline
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
            \HackVSpace%
            \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{Y:}}]%
                \item \HackStrut\texttt{some more text fff yyy}%
            \end{itemize}%
            \HackVSpace%
            }%
}%

\bigskip


\noindent
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}%
            \HackVSpace%
            \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{X:}}]%
                \item \HackStrut\texttt{some text fff yyy}%
            \end{itemize}%
            \HackVSpace%
            \end{minipage}}%
%
\newline
\colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}%
            \HackVSpace%
            \begin{itemize}[label={\small \texttt{Y:}}]%
                \item \HackStrut\texttt{some more text fff yyy}%
            \end{itemize}%
            \HackVSpace%
            \end{minipage}%
}%

\end{document}
```